# How to delete rows if my range does not equal today's date?

Tags: excel, date, formatting, autofilter

I'm a complete beginner attempting a macro for the first time. I want to remove entire rows of a sheet if the date in column K does not equal today's date. Outside of the code having some sort of syntax error that I can't remedy, I believe the data dump's Column K is not formatted as a date to capture the code I'm trying to run.

Here is the code I have so far. Please be gentle on someone who is trying to self teach using online resources :)

```
Sub GetTodaysPopulation()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TradeExData")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TradeExData").Activate

With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

With MyRange
    .AutoFilter([Field:=11], [Criteria1: <> Date])
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
End With

With MySheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: pretty good for your first procedure :) ...  Here's some help: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TradeExData").Activate` can be removed. `([` and this `])` are invalid syntax in the `AutoFilter` arguments. That line is written like this: `.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= "<>" & Date` Remove them too. As far as the date value in the cell, hard to comment without seeing the data itself.

Comment: Thank you @ScottHoltzman ! I realize the redundancy with "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TradeExData").Activate" now. After adjusting my autofilter per your instruction, I now have a compile error (Invalid of unqualified sequence) in the "Set MyRange = .Range..." line. Is this because I cannot nest ".Cells" in ".Range"?

Comment: That statement looks great to me as written. Not sure what the error is. What are the values in LastRow and LastCol?